# Porque o type='date' não funciona no Firefox?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox

Estava testando um script para calcular juros e percebi que meu código não funciona no `Google Chrome`, mas se eu abrir o mesmo script no `Mozilla` ele funciona perfeitamente.

O que será que pode ser?

```js
    elementsArray = document.querySelectorAll('input');
    elementsArray.forEach(function(elem) {
        elem.addEventListener("input", function() {
            calcula();
        });
    });

    function calcula() {
        vencimento = document.getElementById("datavenc").value;
        pagamento = document.getElementById("datapag").value;

        venc_array = vencimento.split("/");
        vencimento = venc_array[2] + "-" + venc_array[1] + "-" + venc_array[0];

        pagt_array = pagamento.split("/");
        pagamento = pagt_array[2] + "-" + pagt_array[1] + "-" + pagt_array[0];


        d1 = new Date(vencimento);
        d2 = new Date(pagamento);

        dias_atraso = parseInt((d2 - d1) / (24 * 3600 * 1000));

        valortit = parseFloat(document.getElementById("valortitulo").value);
        outrasdesp = document.getElementById("despesas").value;
        outrasdesp = (outrasdesp == "") ? 0 : parseFloat(outrasdesp);

        juros = ((valortit * .05) / 30) * (dias_atraso);

        if (!isNaN(dias_atraso) && !isNaN(juros)) {
            document.getElementById("diasematraso").value = dias_atraso;
            document.getElementById("juros").value = juros.toFixed(2).replace(".", ",");
            document.getElementById("valortotal").value = (valortit + juros + outrasdesp).toFixed(2).replace(".", ",");
        }
    }
```

```html
<fieldset style="position:relative; height:200px;  float:left;  width:360px;">
    <legend>Calcular Juros</legend>

    <label>Data de Vencimento:</label>
    <input id="datavenc" type="date" class="form-control" /><br />

    <label>Data de Pagamento: </label>
    <input id="datapag" type="date" class="form-control" /><br />

    <label>Valor do Titulo: </label>
    <input id="valortitulo" type="text" class="form-control" /><br />

    <label>Outras Despesas: </label>
    <input id="despesas" type="text" class="form-control" /><br />
    <br />

    <label>Dias em Atraso: </label>
    <input id="diasematraso" type="text" class="form-control" disabled/><br />

    <label>Juros: </label>
    <input id="juros" type="text" class="form-control" disabled/><br />

    <label>Valor Total a Pagar: </label>
    <input id="valortotal" type="text" class="form-control" disabled/>
</fieldset>
```

**Google Chrome**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Mozilla**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Removi minha resposta pelo seguinte motivo: Ao fazer o teste no meu Notebook usando o navegador Chromium, o código não funcionou, mas ao testar no Google Chrome o mesmo funcionou, informando a data atual como vencimento e a data do pagamento 10 dias após, com o valor de `R$ 500` obteve o valor do juros `R$ 8,33` esta certo ?

Comment: Está sim, o script é pra calcular juros de boletos atrasados.

Comment: @SmokeRohden expliquei porque seu código não funciona em ambos os browsers e troquei o titulo da sua pergunta para ficar um pouco mais ampla atingindo mais leitores.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Porque seu código funciona no Chrome?

O `type='date'` não é suportado pelo `Firefox`.

Nessa parte do código ambos os navegadores irão gerar resultados diferentes.

```
 venc_array = vencimento.split("/");
 vencimento = venc_array[2] + "-" + venc_array[1] + "-" + venc_array[0];

 pagt_array = pagamento.split("/");
 pagamento = pagt_array[2] + "-" + pagt_array[1] + "-" + pagt_array[0];
```

O **Google Crome** entende o `type=date` então valor retornado será `Ano-Mês-Dia`.
`Split` em `Ano-Mês-Dia` não irá separar por nada, então a concatenação do resultado será  `undefined` + `undefined` + `valor`. Por isso seu código não funciona.

O `Mozila` Firefox retornará  `Dia/Mês/Ano` resultando em um calculo correto.

Troque o `type='date'` para `type='text'` e o código funcionará em ambos os navegadores.

## [How to get HTML 5 input type=“date” working in Firefox and/or IE 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22983013/how-to-get-html-5-input-type-date-working-in-firefox-and-or-ie-10)

O `type=date` não é uma especificação real neste momento. É um conceito que o `Google` veio e está em suas especificações(não oficial) e é parcialmente suportado pelo `Chrome`.

O autor da resposta diz:

> Eu não confiaria nesse tipo de entrada neste momento. Seria bom ter,
>   mas não prevejo que este realmente o faça. O motivo n.° 1 é que coloca
>   muito carga no navegador para determinar a melhor interface do usuário
>   para uma entrada um pouco complicada. Pense nisso de uma perspectiva
>   responsiva, como todos os fornecedores saberiam o que funcionará
>   melhor com a sua IU, com 400 pixels, 800 pixels e 1200 pixels de
>   largura?

```js
function calcula() {
    vencimento = document.getElementById("datavenc").value;
    pagamento = document.getElementById("datapag").value;

    venc_array = vencimento.split("/");
    vencimento = venc_array[2] + "-" + venc_array[1] + "-" + venc_array[0];

    pagt_array = pagamento.split("/");
    pagamento = pagt_array[2] + "-" + pagt_array[1] + "-" + pagt_array[0];

    d1 = new Date(vencimento);
    d2 = new Date(pagamento);

    var dias_atraso = parseInt((d2 - d1) / (24 * 3600 * 1000));

    valortit = parseFloat(document.getElementById("valortitulo").value);
    outrasdesp = document.getElementById("despesas").value;
    outrasdesp = (outrasdesp == "") ? 0 : parseFloat(outrasdesp);

    var juros = ((valortit * .05) / 30) * (dias_atraso);

    if (!isNaN(dias_atraso) && !isNaN(juros)) {
        document.getElementById("diasematraso").value = dias_atraso;
        document.getElementById("juros").value = juros.toFixed(2).replace(".", ",");
        document.getElementById("valortotal").value = (valortit + juros + outrasdesp).toFixed(2).replace(".", ",");
    }
}
```

```html
<fieldset style="position:relative; height:200px;  float:left;  width:360px;">
    <legend>Calcular Juros</legend>

    <label>Data de Vencimento:</label>
    <input id="datavenc" type="text" class="form-control" />
    <br />

    <label>Data de Pagamento: </label>
    <input id="datapag" type="text" class="form-control" />
    <br />

    <label>Valor do Titulo: </label>
    <input id="valortitulo" type="text" class="form-control" />
    <br />

    <label>Outras Despesas: </label>
    <input id="despesas" type="text" class="form-control" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <button onclick='calcula()'>Calcula</button>
    <label>Dias em Atraso: </label>
    <input id="diasematraso" type="text" class="form-control" disabled/>
    <br />

    <label>Juros: </label>
    <input id="juros" type="text" class="form-control" disabled/>
    <br />

    <label>Valor Total a Pagar: </label>
    <input id="valortotal" type="text" class="form-control" disabled/>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 1):

**ATUALIZAÇÃO**

Para aumentar a compatibilidade com os navegadores, troque as linhas (o IE não suporta `forEach`):

```
elementsArray = document.querySelectorAll('input');
elementsArray.forEach(function(elem) {
   elem.addEventListener("input", function() {
     calcula();
   });
});
```

Por:

```
elementsArray = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for(x=0;x<elementsArray.length;x++){
    elementsArray[x].addEventListener("input", function(){
        calcula();
    });
}
```

---

Você pode checar se o navegador não tem suporte ao `type="date"` e criar a data de forma diferente. Basta checar apenas pelo primeiro `input` com o `type="date"`:

```
if(document.getElementById("datavenc").type !== "date"){
    // para o Firefox e IE que não suportam type="date"
    venc_array = vencimento.split("/");
    pagt_array = pagamento.split("/");
    vencimento = venc_array[2] + "-" + venc_array[1] + "-" + venc_array[0];
    pagamento = pagt_array[2] + "-" + pagt_array[1] + "-" + pagt_array[0];
}
```

```js
elementsArray = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for(x=0;x<elementsArray.length;x++){
 elementsArray[x].addEventListener("input", function(){
  calcula();
 });
}

function calcula(){
 vencimento = document.getElementById("datavenc").value;
 pagamento = document.getElementById("datapag").value;

 if(document.getElementById("datavenc").type !== "date"){
  venc_array = vencimento.split("/");
  pagt_array = pagamento.split("/");
  vencimento = venc_array[2] + "-" + venc_array[1] + "-" + venc_array[0];
  pagamento = pagt_array[2] + "-" + pagt_array[1] + "-" + pagt_array[0];
 }


 d1 = new Date(vencimento);
 d2 = new Date(pagamento);

 dias_atraso = parseInt((d2 - d1) / (24 * 3600 * 1000));

 valortit = parseFloat(document.getElementById("valortitulo").value);
 outrasdesp = document.getElementById("despesas").value;
 outrasdesp = (outrasdesp == "") ? 0 : parseFloat(outrasdesp);

 juros = ((valortit * .05) / 30) * (dias_atraso);

 if (!isNaN(dias_atraso) && !isNaN(juros)) {
  document.getElementById("diasematraso").value = dias_atraso;
  document.getElementById("juros").value = juros.toFixed(2).replace(".", ",");
  document.getElementById("valortotal").value = (valortit + juros + outrasdesp).toFixed(2).replace(".", ",");
 }
}
```

```html
<fieldset style="position:relative; height:200px;  float:left;  width:360px;">
   <legend>Calcular Juros</legend>

   <label>Data de Vencimento:</label>
   <input id="datavenc" type="date" class="form-control" /><br />

   <label>Data de Pagamento: </label>
   <input id="datapag" type="date" class="form-control"/><br />

   <label>Valor do Titulo: </label>
   <input id="valortitulo" type="text" class="form-control"/><br />

   <label>Outras Despesas: </label>
   <input id="despesas" type="text" class="form-control"/><br />
   <br />

   <label>Dias em Atraso: </label>
   <input id="diasematraso" type="text" class="form-control" disabled/><br />

   <label>Juros: </label>
   <input id="juros" type="text" class="form-control" disabled/><br />

   <label>Valor Total a Pagar: </label>
   <input id="valortotal" type="text" class="form-control" disabled/>
</fieldset>
```