# E possivel editar o estilo do input date html 5

Tags: html5

Utilizo este calendário `<input type="date">`

Pesquisei sobre ele mas até o momento não achei nada sobre sua formatação `css`. Queria saber se é possível costumizá-lo e como posso fazer isso.

Se houver outros calendários estou aberto a sugestões.

```html
<input type="date" class="form-control input-titulo" id="description-input" />
```

Comment: Marcelo, você está falando do datepicker do jquery? do input type="date"?

Comment: input date, posso ter confundido

Comment: irei editar para deixar mais claro

Comment: Existem alguns plugins com javascript para estilizar e melhorar as funcionalidades para campos de data, segue um exemplo: https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Comment: fica claro qual calendario se trata, e se e possivel edita-lo em css, pois preciso de um calendario que fique responsivo em mobile

Comment: Não entendi o que você quis dizer com o comentário acima, de qualquer forma não são todos os navegadores que por padrão suportam `<input type="date">`, como já sugerido eu pesquisaria a respeito do datepicker do Jquery UI

Comment: melhorei a resposta acima

Comment: É bom saber que o input type = 'date' é uma especificação do Crome: [Porque o type='date' não funciona no Firefox?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/246558/porque-o-type-date-n%C3%A3o-funciona-no-firefox/246728#246728)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Abaixo coloquei um exemplo do uso de `datepicker` do `jquery` com seu tema base, neste [link](http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css) você pode ver o `css` do tema base (basta buscar por `datepicker` e você verá algumas de suas classes e propriedades).

```js
//http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/
//https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

$( function() {
   $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker();
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

 
<div>
  Data: 
  <input type="text" class="datepicker">
</div>
```